# How to check if the session is set in header.php

Tags: php, html

I have more than 30 pages and for 20 of them has to be seen only by user so I would like to check if the user is logged in by using this if statement.

```
if($_SESSION['username']){
//Display Page (All HTML code is here.)
}else{
 header("Location: index.php");
}
```

The question is I don't wanna type the same thing for every page. So, I thought I can type this part in header.php

```
if($_SESSION['username']){
```

and this part in footer.php

```
}else{
 header("Location: index.php");
}
```

But it doesn't work like that. I wonder what can I do? What is the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a file:
`if(!$_session['username']){
   header("location: index.php");
}`

and everywhere you need it:
`require("myfile.php");`

Comment: Yes, This is prefect. Exactly that's what I need. Thank you very much.

Comment: I should also add session_start(); to that file I guess. Much better.

Comment: exactly. U're welcome
Personnaly i use:
`<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
//authorised user?
if(!isset($_SESSION['monutilisateur'])){
 header("location:log.php");
}
//deconnexion
if(isset($_POST['decon'])&&$_POST['decon']=='quit'){
 $_SESSION['monutilisateur']=NULL;
 unset($_SESSION['monutilisateur']);
 header("location:log.php");
}
?>`